# Complete example of Polymer Two Way Binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

The polymer documentation has the following two way binding example:

```
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'custom-element',
        properties: {
          someProp: {
            type: String,
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
    ...

    <!-- changes to "value" propagate downward to "someProp" on child -->
    <!-- changes to "someProp" propagate upward to "value" on host  -->
    <custom-element some-prop="{{value}}"></custom-element>
```

I'm looking for a complete example that includes the design of the child, programmatic and interactive events the can cause upward and downward propagation of the `{{value}} property, and a demo of of the complete setup / example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some examples on js fiddle that demonstrate different ways of binding:

- Two-way binding:

  ```
  https://jsfiddle.net/tej70osf/
  ```
- One-way binding: notify is **not set** on value property of the child element:

  ```
  https://jsfiddle.net/tej70osf/1/
  ```
- One-way binding: notify is **set to true** true on value property of the child element however the value property is bound using square brackets [[value]] instead of {{value}}:

  ```
  https://jsfiddle.net/tej70osf/2/
  ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks - these make sense - Just curious whether the ui renders for you.  When I click run nothing renders...?

Comment: Yes it does render. is https://polygit.org/components/ accessible from your network?

Comment: My adblocker in firefox was causing it not to run - Switched to chrome and now it runs fine - Thanks again!

Comment: I think some of the certificates are invalid on the resources used in those Fiddles...

Comment: Ahmad I am proud of you

Answer (score 3):

```
<dom-module id="user-demo">
<template> 
<paper-input label="FIRST NAME" value="{{firstName}}"></paper-input>
</template>
</dom-module>
<user-demo></user-demo>
```

In your javascript code:

```
 Polymer({
        is: 'user-demo',
        properties: {
            firstName: {
                type: String,
                value: 'John',
                notify: true
            }
        }
});
```

Check out the following fiddle for the full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/meenakshi_dhanani/6ffwh0qv/

I tried to use more polymer elements and two way binding. Hope it helps